# How to calculate sunrise and sunset on on a given date and location?

Tags: time, sunrise, sunset

I have a given date at any time in future or past eg: 2016-04-23 or 2022-05-12
Now given at any location(lat,lng). How do i find the time of sunrise or sunset.

Answer (score 2):

#### Assuming you mean this in practical sense:

Just use one of the numerous free websites that give this data:

Eg. https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1224686065

[image: website screenshot]

#### Assuming you want to know about the math:

Check out the [sunrise equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation)

Comment: I am not asking what's available on the internet.

Comment: @SureshChaudhari Are you saying the sunrise equation isn't what you're looking for? Pretty much every method for computing sunrise/sunset is on the Internet, including the methods used by NASA.

Comment: But that site limits the range of dates.